# aptly repo on S3 minio/aws

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, apt, minio, repo

I want to ask if it's possible to make aptly repo on minio S3 bucket?
At now I'm trying to setup aptly repo on AWS bucket but got the following error:
***ERROR: published S3 storage spin-jenk-udemy-test not configured***
Where I can see detailed info about this error? (detailed log of error)

```
"spin-jenk-udemy-test": {
            "region": "eu-west-1",
            "bucket": "spin-jenk-udemy-test",
            "endpoint": "http://10.19.2.5:9000",
            "awsAccessKeyID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "awsSecretAccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the bucket according to the code I gave below.

Example: Create a new bucket named "spin-jenk-udemy-test" on https://s3.amazonaws.com.

```
./mc mb s3/storage spin-jenk-udemy-test --region=us-west-1
```

Example: Create a new bucket named "spin-jenk-udemy-test" on https://play.min.io.

```
./mc mb play/spin-jenk-udemy-test
```

For more information on creating buckets, you can refer to the following web address.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html